# How do I display a list of strings in JSF which also needs to be editable?

Tags: jsf

I have a backing bean which has a property called List cites where Cite has a string property called "value" .. In the init method I am fetching the values stored as a comma separated string, splitting them into individual strings constructing a list and displaying the list of cites. But I also want to give the users ability to add more cites on top of existing ones/edit existing cite content. How can I do that ? The code below is the jsf in xhtml but it doesn't work for me ..

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 3px 3px;">
                    <fieldset>                          
                        <legend>Cites Affected</legend>
                        <h:dataTable value="#{dataEntry.cites}" var="citeAffected">
                            <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header" >
                                <h:outputText value="Cite"/>
                            </f:facet>    
                            <h:inputText value="#{citeAffected.value}"/>
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>
                    <h:commandButton value="Add cite" process="@this" action="#{dataEntry.addCite}"/>                       
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

In the backing bean .. this is what I have

```
DataEntry
{
private List<CiteAffected> cites = new ArrayList<CiteAffected>();

public void addCite()
{
cites.add(new CiteAffected());
} 

public void editMetadata()
{
//update the db object 
}
private void init()
{

// get the value from database as a comma separated string
for(String citeAffected : Arrays.asList(sourceManualLoadProperties.getCitesAffected().split(",")))
            {
                CiteAffected cite = new CiteAffected();
                cite.setValue(citeAffected);
                this.cites.add(cite);
}           }
}
```

The error I am getting is .. As soon as I click on the command button "add cite" all the existing values disappear when I want it to simply add another text box but display the existing values as well ..

```
public class CiteAffected
{
    private String value;

    /**
     *
     * @return the cite affected
     */
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param value the cite affected
     */
    public void setValue(final String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `process="@this"` from `<h:commandButton>` and have your managed bean in `@ViewScoped` at least.

JSF code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="dtCites" value="#{dataEntry.cites}" var="citeAffected">
         <!-- content... -->
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Add cite" action="#{dataEntry.addCite}">
        <f:ajax render="dtCites" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DataEntry {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It is in view scoped. But the text box and all existing values are still getting disappeared even after removing @this

Comment: @Phoenix make sure the `<h:commandButton>` and the `<h:dataTable>` in the same `<h:form>`.

Comment: It is .. so the desired behavior is first form load should fetch the cites from the db .. and everytime I say add cite, a blank text box must be created .. and on submit the current state is saved to the UI

Comment: You can use ajax behavior to add the new cite without refreshing the page. Note that still you have to do a submit to the server.

Comment: This does exactly what I want, but everytime I do "Add cite" the previous text box gets blanked out .. why is that ? I want to be able to add all the cites and then submit ..

Comment: Assuming there's no more code in your page, it should work as is. The way you described means that the managed bean is recreated when submitting the form.

Comment: This is what submit action does, <div id="pageFooter" class="popupFooter">
<div class="buttonGrid">
    <h:commandButton id="saveButton" type="button" value="Save" action="#{manualDataEntryRegText.save}" styleClass="formsubmit" rendered="true">
         <f:ajax onevent="handleSubmitButtonOnEvent" execute="pageForm"/>
       </h:commandButton>
   <c:verbatim>&nbsp;</c:verbatim>
   <h:commandButton id="cancelButton" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?')) return false; else cancel();" styleClass="formcancel" />    
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: So if I click "add cite" a blank text box appears, i can enter a value in it and if i say submit, it saves the value next time I bring up the UI dialog box, I see the value .. but if I do add cite twice, the previous text box after the first add cite click which has some value that I just entered gets blanked out ..

Comment: I guess the problem is that you're trying to handle the same data using different managed beans, and you should not do that, instead keep everything in the same managed bean.

Comment: I think the issue is the render is causing the values not to be saved to the backing bean .. how can that be changed ?

Comment: @Phoenix I don't think so. As I've said before, if you put all the code in a new page it will work as expected.

Comment: I created a static class CiteAffected inside the DataEntryBean .. but it still doesn't set the value ?